# ¿porque no funciona el porcentje en html?

Tags: html, css, web, id

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Probe cambiando de navegador, probe sin el uso del live server, tambien con los estilos en linea dentro del div,tambien puse un parrafo con un lorem y solo me toma el ancho y alto del mismo, lo raro es que con pixeles funciona, no anda unicamente con porcentajes.

Comment: Recuerda que cuando usas porcentajes, estos se refieren al ancho y alto del elemento padre. Si el elemento padre no tiene nada (como es tu caso) el 100% de nada es nada. Usa 100vh para el alto y 100vw para el ancho en caso de que quieras poner el div del tamaño del viewport.

Comment: Aparte de esto, sería genial poder ver tu código para así poderte ayudar. Sin código, es bastante difícil saber qué falla.